# Flattening and combining parts of an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, xml, ordereddictionary

I have taken an xml file and changed it to an ordered dict with xmltodict.  It looks something like this:

**XML file**

```
<part_report>
    <metadata>
        <data1>apple</data1>
        <data2>car</data2>
        <data3>date</data3>
    </metadata>
    <parts>
        <part>
        <data4>people</data4>
        <data5>cats</data5>
        <data6>244234</data6>
        </part>
        <part>
        <data4>children</data4>
        <data5>dogs</data5>
        <data6>342342</data6>
        </part>
    </parts>
</part_report>
```

**OrderedDict**

```
fullFile:    OrderedDict([('part_report', OrderedDict([('metadata', OrderedDict([('data1', 'apple'), ('data2', 'car'), ('data3', 'date')])), ('parts', OrderedDict([('part', [OrderedDict([('data4', 'people'), ('data5', 'cats'), ('data6', '244234')]), OrderedDict([('data4', 'children'), ('data5', 'dogs'), ('data6', '342342')])])]))]))])
```

**Goal and Problems**
What I need to do is flatten the data.  I want to combine the metadata data with the parts.part data for each part in parts. The difficulty is that the metadata and parts are at the same level.  If parts were a sublevel of metadata then I can do this.

I have been struggling with this.  I have tried to split the separate data in the OrderedDict (i.e. metadata + part1, metadata + part2, etc) and then combining them.  It is not working.  I'm failing at the 3rd to last line where I try to combine them. Maybe not the best method either.  Open to suggestions.
Ultimate goal is to put this into a dynamodb database.  Thanks!!

**Here is my code:**

```
import xmltodict
import json
import boto3
import os
import datetime
from xml.dom import minidom

# load file
with open('dummy.xml', 'r') as f: 
    #dummyxml ='<root>' +  f.read() + '</root>'
    dummyxml =f.read()
print(dummyxml)
# parse an xml file by name
my_xml = dummyxml

fullFile = xmltodict.parse(my_xml)
print('fullFile:   ',fullFile)
# Serializing json    
json_object = json.dumps(fullFile, indent = 4)   
print('json_object:     ',json_object)  

#want to flatten dictionary by combining metadata part of dictionary with the individual parts part of dictionary
    
allItems = [];
fullFile = xmltodict.parse(my_xml)
print('fullFile:   ',fullFile)
# Serializing json    
json_object = json.dumps(fullFile, indent = 4)   
print('json_object:     ',json_object)  

if("part_report" in fullFile):
    catalog = fullFile["part_report"]
for key, value in catalog.items():
    print('catalog')
    print(key, value) # metadata orderddict and parts ordereddict
    print()
metadata_part=catalog["metadata"]
print('metadata_part')
print(metadata_part)
print()
parts_part = catalog["parts"]
print('parts_part')
print(parts_part)
print()

for  key,value in parts_part.items():
    cor=(key,value)
    combo=metadata_part.update(cor)
    print('combo')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process():
    doc = ET.parse("test.xml")

    metadata = []        # stores values from metadata    
    for node in doc.iter('metadata'):
        for elem in node.iter():
            if re.match(r'data\d', elem.tag):
                metadata.append(elem.text)

    parts_list = []     # stores values from parts/parts
    for parts in doc.findall('./parts/'):
        arr = []
        for part in parts:
            arr.append(part.text)
        parts_list.append(arr)

    results = []        # create desired list of tuples
    for arr in parts_list:
        result = tuple(metadata + arr)
        results.append(result)

    return results

output = process()
print(output)
```

Will output the following:

```
[('apple', 'car', 'date', 'people', 'cats', '244234'), ('apple', 'car', 'date', 'children', 'dogs', '342342')]
```

Comment: actually I would like the metadata to repeat for as many parts there are.
i.e. [('apple', 'car', 'date', 'people', 'cats, '244234'),('apple', 'car', 'date', 'children', 'dogs', '342342')]

Comment: as if parts were really a sublevel of metadata

Comment: Okay, I've made edits to my code:
1. Fed in XML file instead of parsing it as XML string
2. Pushed metadata values into a list
3. Pushed parts data into into a nested list (level determined by part node). 
4. Return list of tuples